# Retry connection on FTPClient(apache commons net) in java

Tags: java

Below is my FTPClient retry method. It has a bug. When the initial connection is success no issues. But if on 2,3 attempts always end up in NullPointerException. Clearly connection is success on retry but when I try to list the remote files it throws the exception.

```
FTPClient ftpConnection(int in, FTPCon objGetFiles) {

    FTPClient  ftp = null;

    if (in < RetryCount) {
        try {
            in = in + 1;
            logger.debug("connecting .........");
            ftp = objGetFiles.connectToServer(FTPServer, FTPPort, FTPUser, FTPPasswd, RDir);
            logger.debug("connected and the ftp object is "+ftp);


        } catch (IOException ioe) {

            logger.debug(ioe.toString());
            logger.debug("sleeping for " + (RetrySleep / 1000) + " sec");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(RetrySleep);
                logger.debug("retrying connection");
                ftpConnection(in, objGetFiles);

            } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                logger.debug(iex.toString());
            }

        }
    } else {
        logger.debug("maximum retry exceed.");
    }

    return ftp;

}
```

---

```
    DEBUG Starter - retrying connection
    DEBUG Starter - connecting .........
    DEBUG FTPCon - connecting to server ....
    DEBUG FTPCon - 230 Logged on
    DEBUG FTPCon - changing working directory
    DEBUG FTPCon - 250 CWD successful. "/tmp" is current directory.
    DEBUG Starter - connected and the ftp object is      org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient@51e2b2a6
    DEBUG Starter - java.lang.NullPointerException
```

---

```
    FTPFile n[] = ftp.listFiles();
```

Above is the place where it throws the NullPointerException. I Believe its a bug in retry method(as initial connection always work fine), but so far no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ftpConnection()` recursively, but you are eventually returning only the top-level `ftp` variable since each invocation of `ftpConnection()` has its own `ftp-variable`. The `FTPClient`-object generated by your retry-call gets lost immediately since the result from  `ftpConnection(in, objGetFiles)` isn't assigned to a variable.

As a quick fix do

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(RetrySleep);
            logger.debug("retrying connection");
            ftp = ftpConnection(in, objGetFiles);

        } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
            logger.debug(iex.toString());
        }
```

But I would consider if using recursion is the right way to go or if a loop wasn't better for this kind of problem.